# fast growing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

We run postgresql 9.5.2 in an RDS instance.  One thing we noticed was that a certain table sometimes grow very rapidly in size.

The table in question has only 33k rows and ~600 columns.  All columns are numeric (decimal(25, 6)).   After vacuum full, the "total_bytes" as reported in the following query

```
select c.relname, pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) AS total_bytes
from pg_class c;
```

is about 150MB.   However, we observed this grew to 71GB at one point.  In a recent episode, total_bytes grew by 10GB in a 30 minute period.

During the episode mentioned above, we had a batch update query that runs ~4 times per minute that updates every record in the table.  However, during other times table size remained constant despite similar update activities.

I understand this is probably caused by "dead records" being left over from the updates.  Indeed when this table grow too big simply running vacuum full will shrink it to its normal size (150M).  My questions are

- have other people experienced similar rapid growth in table size in postgresql and is this normal?
- if our batch update queries are causing the rapid growth in table size, why doesn't it happen every time?  In fact I tried to to reproduce it manually by running something like

  update my_table set x = x * 2

but couldn't -- table size remained the same before and after the query.

Comment: 600 columns sounds like bad database design.  It's not surprising that the size can balloon so quickly when rapidly adding records, especially if many of those columns use a substantial amount of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is having 600 columns in a single table, which is never a good idea. This is going to cause a lot of problems, table size is just one of them.

From the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)...

> The actual storage requirement [for numeric values] is two bytes for each group of four decimal digits, plus three to eight bytes overhead.

So `decimal(25, 6)` is something like 8 + (31 / 4 * 2) or about 24 bytes per column. At 600 columns per row that's about 14,400 bytes per row or 14k per row. At 33,000 rows that's about 450 megs.

If you're updating every row 4 times per minute, that's going to leave about 1.8 gigs per minute of dead rows.

1. You should fix your schema design.
2. You shouldn't need to touch every row of a table 4 times a minute.

You should ask a question about redesigning that table and process.

Comment: The other issue with a 600-column table is that the underlying storage is capped at ~8kB per row, so if you actually tried to put a 25-digit number in each of these columns, [it wouldn't even fit...](http://rextester.com/GAKZH12768)

Comment: So why couldn't I reproduce this problem by running update table_name set x = x * 2 which updates every record?

Comment: @yan479 Maybe that fit into existing storage so it didn't have to reallocate? Try setting it to random numbers. Or maybe you need to be in a transaction? Or not in a transaction? Either way, the table is poorly designed, so it's like asking for details about why your flying brick didn't fly.

Comment: @NickBarnes That's only a limit for fixed precision columns, they have to fit into one page which is 8k by default. You can increase the page size, but I don't know how recommended that is, and maybe the OP did that. Variable precision can go up to 400 GB. [See TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) and the [FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F).

Comment: @Schwern: The TOAST strategy for `NUMERIC` defaults to `MAIN`, i.e. no out-of-line storage, and besides, these values are well below the 2kB TOAST threshold. But out-of-line storage wouldn't help anyway, as the TOAST pointer itself is 18 bytes, so 600 of these would still fill an 8kB page. Yes, you can tune the page size if you're willing to compile your own packages, but I don't think that's an option on OP's RDS instance.

Comment: @Schwern I think you are right regarding why I couldn't reliably reproduce the problem -- looks like once the table have grown it will have some spare space for future growth.  I don't know the exact mechanism.  Perhaps it over allocate space anticipating future growth, or auto vacuum demon kicked in to reclaim some space.   If I do a vacuum full first I could see the space growth reliably once I run the update query.

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed me to https://begriffs.com/posts/2016-04-19-postgres-adores-vacuum.html which is what I am looking for.